# How to avoid Input matrix is not invertible error in RNN model when estimated matrix used as covariance matrix of a MVN distribution

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, determinants

I am trying to build an RNN model where the covariance matrix is estimated with mean and used to calculate log probability of that multivariate normal distribution.
For getting the covariance matrix I am estimating the triangular matrix first and then converting it to square matrix. with the following,

```
X_list=list of triangular matrix components like 6 numbers for a 3*3 matrix (for n*n matrix, n(n+1)/2 )
mean=list of n numbers for n*n MVN distribution

X_upper = tfp.math.fill_triangular(X_list, upper=True)
X_symm = 0.5 * (X_upper + tf.transpose(X_upper, perm=[0,2,1]))
cov=tf.matmul(X_symm, tf.transpose(X_symm, perm=[0,2,1]))

dist = tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalTriL(loc=mean, scale_tril=tf.linalg.cholesky(cov))
return tf.reduce_mean(-dist.log_prob(sample))
```

I am getting the following error

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Input matrix is not invertible.
```

What modification can I or should I add so that I don't get a matrix which is not invertible?